# What html tags support the onload/onerror javascript event attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, onload, onerror

I'm familiar with the typical use of `onload`, as in the following:

```
<body onload="alert('Hello, World!');">
...
</body>
```

What are all the html elements that fire a load event? (thus executing javascript supplied in an onload attribute)

For example, `img` is one such tag that will execute the javascript supplied in an `onload` attribute when `some.png` has loaded:

```
<img onload="someImgLoaded()" src="some.png" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

'onload' is supported by the following HTML tags:

> `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <link>, <script>`

And the following Javascript objects:

> `image, layer, window`

Comment: You'd think that #Bill the Lizard will naturally be aesthetically familiar with the Rhinoceros book, where this is easy to find. (Javascript the Definitive Guide - O'Reilly, of course.)

Comment: Actually, HTML4.01 only allows `onload` in <frameset> and <body> (source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-onload ), and I *think* there are some cross-browser issues with `onload` for script tags

Comment: No offense or anything, but I have to -1 this. Your staggering reputation facilitates others to take your answer as 'scripture' and leave it at that (including me, if I didn't know better for this particular answer). Since there are many other factors to consider (most of which were stated by Christoph), this can be harmful for the same reasons that w3schools can be. I would think that this question should have been more thorough to begin with or, at least, be updated to reflect current standards. Shoot me a comment if you edit this so I can un-downvote it.

Answer (score 10):

Below is a much more comprehensive list of elements that fire a load event when the requested resource finishes downloading:

```
body # (just fires a load event, doesn't make requests itself)
img
image
link
iframe
frameset
frame
script
embed
object
video ?
  source
  track
audio ?
  source
svg
<input type="image" src="submit.gif" alt="Submit">
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.swf"></object>
<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
webgl?
```

For the most coverage, it's best to consider that all html elements referencing a url will result in a request and fire a `load` or `error` event when that request for the succeeds or fails. So, basically, any element with a `src` or `href` attribute, except for these tags:

```
a
# What else? Not sure off hand..
```

And including the `body` tag, because it ironically doesn't have a `src` OR `href` attribute.

Below is some rough javascript for discovering these elements:

```
var tagsToIgnore = ['a'];

['src', 'href'].forEach(function(attr) {
  console.log('====' + attr + '====');
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*[' + attr + ']')).forEach(function(el){
    if (!~tagsToIgnore.indexOf(el.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
      console.log(el.tagName);
    }
  });
});
console.log('body # :trollface:');
```

Also, with the "everything with src or href" method, you ignore irrelevant  or other tags that typically have a src or href attribute, but not always.

Other things that can have network failures:

- Application Cache
- XMLHttpRequest
- WebSocket
- PeerConnection (WebRTC)
- From: http://docs.webplatform.org/w/index.php?search=onerror&fulltext=+&title=Special%3ASearch

`onload` and `onerror` attributes can be useful to keeping track of whether or not your user has an active internet connection, which is something I'm attempting to address with my library check-online.js: http://github.com/devinrhode2/check-online

There is some obvious testing to be done to see whether or not

Comment: A "much more comprehensive list" should include information about what version of HTML it applies too.

Comment: At this point I don't know who would be dealing with anything other than html 5...

Answer (score 2):

`onload` is an event specific to the `body`, `frame`, `iframe`, `img`, `link`, and `script` elements. Basically anything which represents a resource to be loaded. For `body`, that is the document in question. For the others, each is fairly obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Many elements have the onload event. You can find them [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp)

But if you want to test the loading of the DOM, then it's best to use the [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.onload).
It's also recommended that you separate the javascript code from the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onload.asp), you can use `onload` with: `<body>`, `<frame>`, `<frameset>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<link>`, and `<script>`.