# What html tags support the onload javascript event?

Tags: javascript, html

I know that  `img` `body` and `iframe` allow you to add `onload=` to the tag and have to execute.   What other tags support the `onload` action?  Do you know of a list of all tags and the actions the support?

Comment: `frameset` and `object` s are candidates as well. It's hard to find an official overview. The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events) even kind of insinuates it's somehow generic: "For elements, it fires when the target element and all of its content has finished loading" (but I'm sure it is not)

Comment: frameset tags support it too.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can you put the JavaScript onload event anywhere besides in the body tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/can-you-put-the-javascript-onload-event-anywhere-besides-in-the-body-tag)

Comment: I don't trust the dupe because the accepted answer quotes w3schools. The HTML 4.01 DTDs show the event only for `body` and `frameset`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specs for html4 only mention `body` and `frameset`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.3

I think it's browser dependent.

Comment: But according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html it's only valid on the BODY element... and quirksmode currently doesn't cover load/unload (http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html) ... so the plot thickens.

Comment: @Pekka Indeed. You are correct. Here the "loose" DTD for reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/loosedtd.html

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it on `<script>` tags except IE where you need `onreadystatechange` for the same effect.

I think it also works on `<object>` elements in some browsers (but just a few).