# onload is not working but onmouseover is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What html tags support the onload javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272002/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-javascript-event)

I have a page where i am trying to load same page on facebox style and if I place `onmouseover` link on that page and hover it just works fine but when I try with `onload` it is not triggering the event.

Here is my `onmouseover` event:

```
<a id="curpo" onmouseover="$.image({ ajax: \'http://way2enjoy.com/jquery/threadpreview/'.$thread['id'].'\' });return false;" 
    class="uiMediaThumb uiMediaThumbLarge uiMediaThumbAlb uiMediaThumbAlbLarge">
    <span id="thumbback" class="uiMediaThumbWrap">
        <img src="http://way2enjoy.com/files/icons/priview.png"></span></a>
```

This works just fine but the below code is not working:

```
<a id="curpo" onload="$.image({ ajax: \'http://way2enjoy.com/jquery/threadpreview/'.$thread['id'].'\' });return false;" 
    class="uiMediaThumb uiMediaThumbLarge uiMediaThumbAlb uiMediaThumbAlbLarge">
    <span id="thumbback" class="uiMediaThumbWrap">
        <img src="http://way2enjoy.com/files/icons/priview.png"></span></a>
```

Here is the live example:
http://way2enjoy.com/forums/viewthread/406828

Just below to red letters  Listen Music Video Online users Photo
magnifier or  zoom icon is there if we keep the cursor over that it shows but it does not show page `onload`.. for testing with `mouseover` you need to change the `onload` to `onmouseover` in Firebug.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272002/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-javascript-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `onload` event is not fired on `a` elements which is the reason why its not working. onload is primarily used for the `body` element. If you want to run some code right after the a element is shown try putting a script tag after it like so:

```
<a id="curpo" class="uiMediaThumb uiMediaThumbLarge uiMediaThumbAlb uiMediaThumbAlbLarge"><span id="thumbback" class="uiMediaThumbWrap"><img src="http://something.com/files/icons/priview.png"></span></a>   
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#curpo").image({ ajax: 'http://something.com/jquery/threadpreview/<?php echo $thread['id']?>' });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried your idea but not working plz guide

Answer (score 1):

Onload event doesn't apply for anchor elements. It's supported by the following tags

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, 
<link>, <script>, <style>
```