# HTML inline javascript function not working

Tags: javascript, html, function

The issue I am having is running the same javascript file which is my lastModified.js it has two function wich are make a random array to spit out as a sentence for basic.html and then also a lastModified function the issue is the lastmodified updates the basic2.html but not the basic2.html how do I put my functions inside the lastModified.js instead of making a huge function and having the ids of the html = the name which is what I am doing putting id all over the htmls and then seeing if they exist if they do the code runs

```
lastModified.js---------------------------------------
window.onload=lastModified;

function lastModified(){
//var lastModified = document.getElementById("modified");
//lastModified.innerHTML=modified;
//document.write(document.lastModified);

var words1= ["yo", "ey", "vato", "esse", "mathematical", "algebraic" ];
var words2= ["wassup", "QUE", "wassapinin", "oooooooooooooooooooo", "ooOoOo"];
var words3= ["homie", "dogg", "PIMP", "THUG"];

var rand1=Math.floor(Math.random() *words1.length);
var rand2=Math.floor(Math.random() *words2.length);
var rand3=Math.floor(Math.random() *words3.length);
var phrase = words1[rand1] + " " +words2[rand2] + " " + words3[rand3];
var phraseElement = document.getElementById("phrase");
phraseElement.innerHTML=phrase;



document.lastModified=lastMod;

var el = document.getElementById('modified');
el.innerHTML=lastMod;

/*
modify lastModified print format

var dt = document.lastModified;    
dt = dt.replace("/", " ");
dt = dt.replace("/", " ");
dt = dt.replace("-", " ");
dt = dt.replace("-", " ");
// '/' or '-' replcae these separtors with empty space
// Now your string can be parsed to Date Object
var anotherDateObject = new Date(Date.parse(dt));
alert(anotherDateObject + " -- " + anotherDateObject.getHours()); 
*/
}

end of lastModified.js-------------------------------------

basic2.html------------------------------------------------
<html>
<body>
<head>

    <title> Building Blocks to Html</title>




    <script src="lastModified.js"></script> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Hyper Text Markup Language, />
    <meta name="description" content="HTML in easy steps. Introductory tutorial for beginners." / >
    <meta name="author" content="Miguel Castaneda" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all, nofollow" />




    </head>
    <center><a href="#bottom">Bottom</a></center>
    <p id="credit"> <!-- browser picks first one in array if not in cpu then goes to 2nd font //-->
            <tt>
            Programmer: Miguel Castaneda(iSten23)
            <br></br>Last Modified: <p id="modified"></p>
            <BR></br>
            Head First HTML5 Programming
            <br></br>

    </p>
    <p> page two</p>
    </tt>
            <a name="bottom">
            <p id="screenSize">Screen Size: </p>
            <table><tr><td>
<center><small><small>
<a href="basic.html"><img src="arrow1.jpg" height="40" width="40"border="0" alt="Link to next page"></a>

<p id="location"></p>
</small></small></center></td><td>
<center><small><small>

<a href="basic3.html"><img src="arrow.jpg" height="40" width="40"border="0" alt="Link to next page"></a>

</small></small></center></td>
    <tr></table>        

</body>


</html>
end of basic2.html
basic.html-----------
<!doctype html">
<html lang="en">
<html> 
<body>
    <head>



    <script src="lastModified.js"></script> 
    <link href="mainsite.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML, Hyper Text Markup Language, />
    <meta name="description" content="HTML in easy steps. Introductory tutorial for beginners." / >
    <meta name="author" content="Miguel Castaneda" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all, nofollow" />


    <!--
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
    Refreshes same page every 5 seconds 
    //-->

    <!--
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5";

    url=pathname   to refresh another page 
    or 
    url=http        to refresh another url
    //-->

    <!--

    <meta name="robots" content="all, nofollow" />   //instruct robot to read page but not follow links
    <meta name="robots" content="none" />           //instruct robot to prevent from reading pages at all





    //-->


<title>Building Blocks to Html</title>
    </head>

    <!-- 
    background="photos\codingBG.jpg
    for BG p

    to make certain pargraphs a diffrent color
    <p><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000FF">This tezt is blue</font></p>


    //-->



    <center><a href="#bottom">Bottom</a></center>
    <p id="credit"> <!--<font face="Arial, Hevetica, sans-serif"> //--><!-- browser picks first one in array if not in cpu then goes to 2nd font //-->
            <tt>
            Programmer: Miguel Castaneda(iSten23)
            <br></br>Last Modified: <div id="modified"></div>

            <BR></br>
            Head First HTML5 Programming
            <br></br></tt>
            <b><big><big><center>Main Site</center></big></big></b>

    </p>










            <hr></hr>
            <p>Update this code so every section has id so you can link yourself throughout the page</p>
            <br></br>
<h3>h1- h6</h3>
<p id="testh1thru6">
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
<h5>This is h5</h5>
<h6>This is h6</h6>
</p>
<hr></hr>
<p id="englishp" lang="en-us">Paragraph in English</p>
<p id="francais" lang="fr">Paragraphe en Francais</p>

<hr></hr>
<h3>BOLD, ITALICS, SUBSCRIPT AND SUPERSCRIPT, inserted/deleted text</h3>

<p><b>Bold</b> = < b> <br></br> <i>Italics</i> = < i> <br></br> <sub>Subscript</sub> = < sub> <br></br> <sup>Superscript</sup> < sup> <br></br> 
<ins>Inserted Text</ins> = < ins> <br></br> <del>Deleted text</del>= < del> <br></br> <tt>teletype text</tt> <br></br>

<p id="text">This paragraph includes words with <b> bold</b>, <i>italics</i>, superscript E=MC<sup>2</sup> and subscript CO<sub>2</sub> also <ins>inserted text </ins>and <del>deleted text</del> <tt>teletype text</tt></p>
<hr></hr>
    <h3>Break and Horizontal Rule</h3>
    <p> Break(new line) = < br> <br></br> Horizontal Line = < hr></p>
    <br></br>
<p> To put a new line anywhere you need to<br> break</br></p>

<p>For there to be a horizontal line you need hr <hr>like so</hr></p>
<br></br><br></br>3
<hr></hr>

<h3>STRONG & EMPHASIS</h3>
<p>Just always use < b> or < i> Instead of em and strong</p>
<br></br>
<p> Strong and Bold are both same</p>
<p> Em and italics is same</p>
<hr></hr>

<h3>Quotations</h3>
<P>Blockquote is for when the quote is too long and want to link it back to url
<br></br>Blockquote = < blockquote cit="url">< p> did you ever think, and forget to start< /p>
<br></br> Quote = < q>, quote also had cite attribute</P>



<br></br>
<blockquote cite="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/
 Winnie-the-Pooh">
<p>Did you ever stop to think, and forget to start
again?</p>
</blockquote>
<p>As A.A. Milne said, <q>Some people talk to
animals. Not many listen though. That's the
problem.</q></p>

<hr></hr>
<h3>Abbreviations &
Acronyms</h3>
<p>To abbr you < abbr title="Professor">Prof< /abbr>  </p>
<p> HTML just uses the < abbr> element
for both abbreviations and
acronyms.</p>
<br></br>
<p><abbr title="Professor">Prof</abbr> Stephen
Hawking is a theoretical physicist and
cosmologist.</p>
<p><acronym title="National Aeronautics and Space
Administration">NASA</acronym> do some crazy
space stuff.</p> 
<br></br>
<hr></hr>
<h3>ORDERDED LIST</h3>
<P>For a order list you start the list with < ol> and for each item include 
< li> text 
< /li> then < /ol>
like so
</P>

<ol>
<li>Chop potatoes into quarters</li>
<li>Simmer in salted water for 15-20
minutes until tender</li>
<li>Heat milk, butter and nutmeg</li>
<li>Drain potatoes and mash</li>
<li>Mix in the milk mixture</li>
</ol>
<br></br>
<hr></hr>
<h3>UNORDERED LIST</h3>
<P>Same us orderded list except use < ul> to surround the items like so </P>
<br></br>
<ul>
<li>1kg King Edward potatoes</li>
<li>100ml milk</li>
<li>50g salted butter</li>
<li>Freshly grated nutmeg</li>
<li>Salt and pepper to taste</li>
</ul>
<br></br>
<hr></hr>
<h3>DEINITION LISTS</h3>
<P> start with the < dl> < /dl> for ever term include < dt> and for its definition include < dd> 
would look like 

<br></br>
<dl>
<dt>Sashimi</dt>
<dd>Sliced raw fish that is served with
condiments such as shredded daikon radish or
ginger root, wasabi and soy sauce</dd>
<dt>Scale</dt>
<dd>A device used to accurately measure the
weight of ingredients</dd>
<dd>A technique by which the scales are removed
from the skin of a fish</dd>
<dt>Scamorze</dt>
<dt>Scamorzo</dt>
<dd>An Italian cheese usually made from whole
cow's milk (although it was traditionally made
from buffalo milk)</dd>
</dl>
<P id="leftoff">LEFT OFF ON PAGE 68</P>
<hr></hr>
<p> Updated 3/4/2014 </p>

<h1>Phrase-o-matic says:</p>
<p id="phrase"></p>

<hr></hr>
<p>Geo-Location Book 2 page 173 </p>
<div id="location">
your location will go here</div>

<hr></hr>

<font  color="purple"><p > This paragraph is supposed to be purple</p></font>
<p id="purplesentence">This sentence will later be moved to purple with CSS</p>

<hr></hr>

<small>
<p>Site for picking Hexadecimal for Html and CSS</p>
<P><a href="www.­w3schools.­com/­tags/­ref_colorpicker .asp">W3Schools HTML Color</a>
    </P></small>

    <hr></hr>


   <a name="bottom">
   <center><small><small><a href="basic2.html"><img src="arrow.jpg" height="40"                                              

   width="40"border="0" alt="Link to next page"></a></small></small></center>
   </body>

   <center>
   <small><small>    
   <div id="nav">
                                                                <table>

   <tr><th>

   <a href="index.html">Home</a>  &nbsp; &nbsp; </th><th>   <!-- 5 table spacing   links//-->
   <a href="html.html">HTML</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; </th><th>
   <a href="python.html">Python</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; </th><th>
   <a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; </th><th>
   <a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a> 
   </tr></th>


                                                   </table>
   </div>
   </small></small>
   </center>
   </table>
   </html>
   basic.html end of file
```

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here is why:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Did you know you have two `<html>` opening tags

Comment: One suggestion I would make (not related to the code) is to try to structure your written thoughts into sentences, separated by periods. Paragraphs are a great idea too. I've read your question three times and I still can't figure out what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you want to be using an "onload" for ([What html tags support the onload javascript event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272002/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-javascript-event))

Try just inlining the js, and referencing the element:

```
<p id="modified2"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var el = document.getElementById('modified2');
  myMod.call(el);
</script>
```