# Why window.onload works and onload="" does not work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So for some reason my canvas wasn't being applied when called through onload, I've tried other events and they work, I've tried changing where onload is placed (the footer, p and canvas tags) but that didn't work, and i tested the script functionality by placing it at the bottom outside of a function which does work

Ive tried another website which I did that had onload and canvas' and they work so after looking up possible solutions I ended up having to add windows.onload in the script area and it fixed it

What I would like to know is why doesn't the onload in the tags work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script>
function draw(){
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(17,17,15,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
}
window.onload= draw;
</script>
</head>

<footer>
<p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="34" height="34" onload="draw()"></canvas>
</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your `<body>` tag??

Comment: @Cheery I removed everything else, this was just a test page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canvas onload event isn't firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670482/canvas-onload-event-isnt-firing)

Comment: @Cheery The issue was fixed, I was just looking for a explanation as to why the onload event wasnt working, as per answer below its said that it only works in the body tag, which also fixes the problem. But Id like to know why it only work for the body tag also.

Comment: Not every tag has this property and event - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4272002/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-javascript-event and `canvas` does not have it - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp compare with events list of `body` - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because only the body element and `img` element can fire the `onload()` event.

Just simply use the function name `draw()` inside the script tag like `<script> draw(); </script>` after the canvas tag..

Comment: I didnt try adding onload to the body tag, I never knew that it couldnt only be used there.

Comment: @KevinKnapp just have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670482/canvas-onload-event-isnt-firing..and please accept my answer if it helped ..Thanx

Comment: @AvinashBabu - _"only the body element can fire the onload() event."_ - This is **false**. The `img` element also supports this event.