# Hide/Show div in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello all i was trying to hide/show a loading div but theres the problem: After the page loads the div appears again...Heres the code i'm using

```
 <div id="LoadContent" style="visibility: visible">
            Please wait while we check our databases....
            <br/>
            <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="LoadImg">
        </div>

document.getElementById('LoadContent').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

Comment: Where's the code that determines whether the page has loaded? Are you using any AJAX? One thing I would change right off the bat is instead of using the `visibility` property, use the `display` property with block/none.

Comment: have you tried putting the javascript as the last content of the page - by this most of the pages element would have been loaded. You can also achieve that using jQuery $(document).ready(...) function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add your javascript to `<body onload="">`, that way it will hide your div when the page has finished rendering.

css takes prescedence over javascript during rendering time, or rerender time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no onload event for divs, [only certain tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/can-you-put-the-javascript-onload-event-anywhere-besides-in-the-body-tag).

However, that doesn't mean you're out of luck.  Why is this particular div taking longer to load than the rest of your html?

For example, if you have large images inside of it, then you could have onload events for these, and show the div when they're all finished loading.

Comment: The problem is that while the page loads(after i press the button) the div hides with no errors, but when the page finishes to load, the div appears again

Comment: @JoãoMarceloBrito Is the button of type "submit"?  If so, your div is hiding momentarily, but then the entire page is being reloaded from the server.  When this happens, all of your html is reset, including your div's "visibility" property.  Not sure if this is your issue, maybe you could edit your question to include the button and it's associated javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You should revert visibility to display and use block/none.

If you follow my steps (later on..) then you will need to get the jquery libraries (add them to your header) for example:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

On the other hand it would be a lot less coding to use jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hidebox(){
    $("#LoadContent").toggle();
}
</script>
```

Your body tag should be like this:

```
<body onload="hidebox()">
```