# Javascript dropdown list working, but displaying empty values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 dropdrown lists written in javascript.Upon loading the page and clicking them, they dropdown and display what would normally be values, except the values are empty.

E.g

```
---------------
|    Gender   |
---------------
|             |<-- Is supposed to show "M"
---------------
|             |<--Is supposed to shown "F"
```

---

My code

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
    AgeDropDown();
    genderlist();
    }
 function AgeDropDown(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileAge");
        for(var i=1;i<100;i++)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= i;
            list.appendChild(opt);
        }
  }

    function genderlist(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileGender");
        var choices=["M","F"];
        for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= choices[i];
            list.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }

    function load(){
    AgeDropDown();
    genderlist();
    }
</script>


</head>
<body onload="load()">
<?php
include("usermenubar.inc");
?>
<form id='UserProfile' name='UserProfile' method='POST' action='editdetails.php'>



<div class='UserDetails'><!--dropdown-->
    Age:<select id='UserProfileAge' name='UserProfileAge' onchange='AgeDropDown()'>
    <option value=''>Please enter your age</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class='UserDetails'><!--Dropdown-->
    Gender:<select id='UserProfileGender' name='UserProfileGender' onchange='genderlist()'>
    <option value=''>Please enter your gender</option>
    </select>
</div>


<input type='submit' name='UserProfileSubmit' value='Save Changes'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `new Option` to dynamically add options..  to an `HTMLSelectElement` using the `add` method...

```
 function AgeDropDown(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileAge");
        for(var i=1;i<100;i++)
        {
           var opt =new Option(i,i) ;
           list.add(opt);
        }
  }

    function genderlist(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileGender");
        var choices=["M","F"];
        for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
        {
          var opt = new Option(choices[i],choices[i]) ;
          list.add(opt);
        }
    }
```

also i noticed a strange thing.. in your markup...

```
<select id='UserProfileAge' name='UserProfileAge' onchange='AgeDropDown()'>
```

and

```
<select id='UserProfileGender' name='UserProfileGender' onchange='genderlist()'>
```

you are calling your both functions everytime the value of the select changes.. so new options will be added in the select.. i don't know why you are doing that??

Comment: I've changed it to onload instead of onchange. Thanks for pointing it out!. I upvoted your answer since i've already accepted an answer

Comment: @Ken select element has no onload option.. look here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes  .. and by the way.. you can unaccept an answer and accept the other one..  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Options can have both value and text.  You're only setting the value, so it will function properly, but not display any text.

The HTML you're generating would look like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="M"></option>
    <option value="F"></option>
</select>
```

You want this:

```
<select>
    <option value="M">M</option>
    <option value="F">F</option>
</select>
```

So, also set the `textContent` of the option elements, and `innerText` for IE support.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this (check out [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ej6vF/) to see it running):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load(){
    AgeDropDown();
    genderlist();
    }
 function AgeDropDown(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileAge");
        for(var i=1;i<100;i++)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= i;
            opt.text = i;
            list.appendChild(opt);
        }
  }

    function genderlist(){
        var list= document.getElementById("UserProfileGender");
        var choices=["M","F"];
        var choicesText=["Male","Female"];
        for(i=0;i<choices.length;i++)
        {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.value= choices[i];
            opt.text = choicesText[i];
            list.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }

    function load(){
    AgeDropDown();
    genderlist();
    }
</script>


</head>
<body onload="load()">
<?php
include("usermenubar.inc");
?>
<form id='UserProfile' name='UserProfile' method='POST' action='editdetails.php'>



<div class='UserDetails'><!--dropdown-->
    Age:<select id='UserProfileAge' name='UserProfileAge' onchange='AgeDropDown()'>
    <option value=''>Please enter your age</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class='UserDetails'><!--Dropdown-->
    Gender:<select id='UserProfileGender' name='UserProfileGender' onchange='genderlist()'>
    <option value=''>Please enter your gender</option>
    </select>
</div>


<input type='submit' name='UserProfileSubmit' value='Save Changes'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```