# JavaScript Using the DOM methods and properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom, methods

Hey guys i have some code here that is supposed to create HTML elements on the page that will display today date next to ID='today' How do use a textnode to write out to the ID? Thanks for any help! Here is my Full code:

HTML:

```
  <body>
  <h1>ToDo List - Date: <span id='today'>&nbsp;</span></h1>

  <div id="todolist">
<p>
    <input type="button" id="additem" value="Add Item">
</p>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div>
<p>
    <input type="button" id="sortitems" value="Sort and Display Items">
</p>

<p id="displayitems">
</p>
   </div>
  </body>
```

Javascript:

```
 var $ = function (id){
return document.getElementById(id);
   }

  var TodaysDate = function () {
  var myDate = new Date();

  var myMonth = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var myDay = myDate.getDate();
  var myYear = myDate.getFullYear();

  var myResponse = myMonth + "/" + myDay + "/" + myYear;

  var myPara = document.createElement("p");
  var myP = document.getElementById('today');
  myP.appendChild(myPara);

  var myText = document.createTextNode(myResponse);
  myPara.appendChild(myText);

  }
  window.onload = function ()
  {
   $("today").onload = TodaysDate;
   $("sortitems").onclick = sortItem;
   $("additems").onclick = addItem;     
  }
```

Comment: Span onload? Onload works for windows/frames and images only

Comment: Interesting use of your `$` function as shorthand for `document.getElementById`. I'd never seen that before -- trying to make it look like JQuery I guess? **+1** for being interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Span onload? Onload is not triggered for a span. Other object do have a load event for example: windows/frames, body, link, script and images

Change

```
 $("today").onload = TodaysDate;
```

To

```
 TodaysDate();
```

and

```
var myPara = document.createElement("p");
var myP = document.getElementById('today');
myP.appendChild(myPara);
var myText = document.createTextNode(myResponse);
myPara.appendChild(myText);
```

To

```
var myPara = document.createElement("p");
var myText = document.createTextNode(myResponse);
myPara.appendChild(myText);

var myP = $('today');
myP.appendChild(myPara);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this line:

```
$("today").onload = TodaysDate;
```

with this line:

```
TodaysDate();
```

because the `SPAN` tag does not support the `onload` event (see **[this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes)**.

Try it out **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ux8Ta/1/)**.