# HTML <A>nchor Tag doesn't show link

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

Using Jquery or Javascript .load functions on a div, I've noticed the `<A>` tag will only show text, not a link, when using Jquery/Javascript load function. I've searched online but gotten nothing relevant. The answer is included below. Loading the included page itself still loads the link.

Note: I guess I have to put this disclaimer: I used the Q&A format when posting.
So please, before offering an answer, read the existing answer. It did fix the issue, yet some a few people have voted this and the answer down for "not enough information" or being incorrect.

Comment: Please include some example markup.

Comment: Please add some code to help us understand what you are trying to ask

Comment: What does "won't show a link" mean? Are you adding an anchor using `load` and it is rendering as plain text that does nothing when you click on it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes

Comment: Thank you @ptrk though it seems to have been changed. A few people have voted this down because they didn't realize it was Q&A format, and Stack doesn't clearly state that. The reason for it was included when I posted it below.

Answer (score -1):

Many different ways of writing HTML are largely accepted, even if they're not "standard methods", and some methods are deprecated. HTML has evolved, and a closing table row (`</TR>`) tag is no longer required, along with self-closing tags (e.g.: `<BR />`).

While there may be other issues causing it, HTML loaded using jQuery seems to be subject to more specific rules when parsing. Maybe someone can be more specific, but I wanted to put this out here since I was confused and found nothing after searching. In this case, make sure that your anchors in the HTML code that are loaded by jQuery contain quotes after `HREF` (eg: `<A HREF"link.htm">`). Modern browsers read it without quotes, so long as there's no space. HTML code parsed using jQuery seems to be less flexible.

So something I never learned in school, but should be kept in mind for troubleshooting that anyone but a pro might not know: If something doesn't seem to work, always fall back on more robust code, even if you want to streamline.

Comment: Probably because there is no `=` sign. `<a href=link.htm>Link</a>` or `<a href="link.htm">Link</a>`

Comment: End tags for table rows have *always* been optional in HTML. Slashes at the end of BR elements have *never* been mandatory in HTML (and weren't even allowed until HTML 5). The rules for quotes around attribute values don't change when you load content with JS instead of directly by loading an HTML document.

Comment: There is an option to make an answer a question Q&A style. It's there for a reason, and I was trying to give anyone information out there who had the same problem.

It does seem to make a different whether you use quotes when it's a #div.load from a file, as it will show simple text in an anchor tag without the quotes, yet will work properly with the quotes there.