# html - how to fill input text on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, onload

I have an HTML form in the view and I need to fill out some input fields with json variables that come from the server. I don't want to write javascript code for each input field, instead, I want to access json variable in the `value` attribute of input tag.

I tested `onload` event for `input` tag but ot does not have any effects.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onload="this.value = 'value';" name="company[name]" />
```

Comment: input tag does not support onload event http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is a pure/vanilla Javascript solution.**

Keep the name of the `<input>` elements same as in the JSON data. The idea is to access the `<input>` with the keys from the JSON data.

Here is the **working code snippet:**

```js
const values = {
  a: 5,
  b: 15
}

const keys = Object.keys(values)
const length = keys.length

for(let i = 0; i < length; i++){
    const key = keys[i]
    document.getElementsByName(key)[0].value = values[key]
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="a" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="b" />
```

Answer (score 10):

`onload` event is work with `<body>` tag and some other tags, or you can also use `window.onload = function(){}` see below sample code

**HTML**

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[name]" id="company_name"/>
```

**JS CODE**

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById("company_name").value = "value";
}
```

PS: `id` will be unique selector so add id attribute in input element.

you can access all element using right selector in `window.onload` event anonymous function

***UPDATE***

suggested by @AlexanderO'Mara

'onload' is supported by the following HTML tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <link>, <script>
```

And the following Javascript objects:

```
image, layer, window
```

Comment: [`onload` is supported by other tags than `body`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes). `input` isn't one of them though.

Comment: Unfortunately, the accepted answer on that question is outdated. The second answer looks more-accurate. Might be simpler to say, `input` does not support `onload`. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('document').ready(function () {
   $('input').val('value')
})
```

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('input').val('value')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="company[name]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
<input type="text" autofocus>
```