# Changing a Link Pop-Up to a "Open When Screen is Loaded" Pop-Up Action

Tags: javascript, html

I need to take the following code that was originally used to open a pop-up message when the user clicked on the image, and change it to open when the webpage finishes loading. How would I go about doing this while keeping the same basic code format (i.e. no <script> in Head?)

I tried changing onclick to onload and this solution did not work.

```html
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'"> 
       <img alt="" src="/Portals/0/Images/Banner/banner-mobile-cafeteria.jpg" class="banner-img" />
</a> 
<div id="light" class="white_content">
   please click 
    <a href="http://midwestfolding.artcobell.com" target="_blank">here</a>.
 (Note, by clicking the link you will be leaving the Midwest Folding Products website. <br /> <br />
 To return, please click <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">here</a>.
</div> <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
```

Comment: If you want your code to execute when the page is finished loading just move the script before closing the `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Ced I would like for it to appear like there is a popup with the rest of the website darkened.

Comment: @Ced I was able to find that approach through Google, however I just want the div to appear (with the rest of the website darkened) and not open another website.

Comment: @Emily Ok I edited my answer to suit your needs. If that answers your question please upvote and accept it as answer by clicking the little "v" under the score of the answer. Ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it makes little sens to me to show an element after page load. You could make the css of the div you want to show `display:block` instead and forget any javascript. But that's not the question so..

If I understood correctly you want to open a pop up when page is loaded:

Javascript:

This will trigger the function to be launched after the page is loaded (and open a pop up):

```
<script>
window.onload = function () { 
   window.open ("http://www.yourlink.com","title");
}

</script>
```

or if it's the visibility you wanna change :

```
<script>
window.onload = function () { 
   document.getElementById("#yourElement").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Using jquery you can open a pop up on page load like this :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
      window.open ("http://www.yourlink.com","title");
    });
});
</script>
```

You then commented you want a dialog to open after the page load which is not your original question but w.e :

For that check [jquery dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Setting modal true will darken the screen behind it. You need to have the jquery library for that (google it).

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Important information">
    hi
</div>

<script>
$("#dialog-message").dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    position: ['center', 'top'],
    show: 'blind',
    hide: 'blind',
    width: 400,
    dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-osx',
    buttons: {
        "YES": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: After playing around with the code a bit, I got it to work on the webpage. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to move your event handler to the `body` tag:

```
<body onload="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
```

Anchors [**do not have onload events**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes), so you can't leave it there.

Comment: This looks very close to a solution, however the CMS I need to use will not allow to me to use the body tag.

Comment: @Emily my first answer was basically that.

Comment: I suspect that you should be learning how to load custom scripts in your CMS rather than hacky workarounds. JavaScript doesn't belong in your markup.