# Insert current url in textfield on page load

Tags: javascript

I want my URL to be displayed in a text field when the page loads.
I tried this but it did not work:

```js
function getUrl() {
  var url = document.URL;
  document.getElementById("textfield").value = url;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" readonly="true" onload="getUrl()" value="">
```

Comment: try: var url = window.location.href;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `onload` attribute will not work on an input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes). Instead, you can set a listener on the window to watch for when the page is "loaded." When it is loaded, call the function:

```js
function getUrl() {
  var url = document.URL;
  document.getElementById("textfield").value = url;
}

window.addEventListener('load', getUrl);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" readonly="true" value="">
```

Comment: worked, thank you :) Can you maybe explain to me why I received a downvote? just for future posts so I know what I could do better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @TomiG, honestly I'm not really sure. I don't see anything specific as to why. Must just be people being over-critical of new users.