# Populating Select with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to populate select options with results from a for cycle but I just can't get it to work. I call the function from the select's onclick but it just doesn't work.

Here's a working JS fiddle *without* the function but I need it to be in a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/610/

And here's what I'm trying to get to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/612/

```js
function populate() {
    var max = new Date().getFullYear() + 1,
        min = max - 9,
        select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');

    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        select.appendChild(opt);
   }
};
```

```html
<select id="selectElementId" onload="populate()"></select>
```

Comment: Have you ever wondered that `<select>` [might not emit an `onload` event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes)? It doesn't really make sense for a `<select>` to say it's loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why using `onload` on the `select` element, try adding the execution of `populate()` function on the [`window load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) using  `window.onload = populate();`

```js
window.onload = populate();
function populate() {
var max = new Date().getFullYear() +1;
var min = max - 9;
    select = document.getElementById('selectElementId');
    
   for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      opt.value = i;
      opt.innerHTML = i;
      select.appendChild(opt);
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="selectElementId" ></select>
```

Comment: Or even better, `onDOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, indeed

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use `document.onload();`

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/t8fdh/616/

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp, you can only use onload on the following tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script> and <style>
```

You can put your onload on the body tag and it will work :)