# how to dynamic distribution ids using jquery and while loop

Tags: jquery

Im have a multiple  select element, I want to set ids for each one dynamically using loop and jquery but its not set,  whats problem??

```
<tbody>
                          <script> var count= 0; 
                          </script>
                          <?php
$con= mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","sdn");
$result= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `nlogos`");
                          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                          ?>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="row"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></th>
                          <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['address']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo '<a target="_blank" 
href='.$row['Fdir'].'>'; echo 'Document'; echo '</a>'; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo '<a target="_blank" 
href='.$row['Ldir'].'>'; echo 'Logo'; echo '</a>'; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['Catogry']; ?></td>
                          <script>
                               count+=1;
                          </script>
                          <td>
<select onload="setid()" onchange="send(this.value, this.id)">
                                  <option selected>Action</option>
                                  <option value="add">+ Add</option>
                                  <option value="delete">- Delete</option>
                              </select>
                              <script>
                                function setid(){
                                    $(this).Attr('id', count);
                                }
                              </script>
                          </td>                               
                        </tr><?php } ?> 
                      </tbody>  

and this also not worked : 
$('select').on('load', function(){
                                    $(this).attr('id', count);
                                  });
```

no errors and also no value returned

Comment: Why you are doing it with jquery. Wo can archive same with php.

Comment: The `load` event [doesn't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/679712/924299) to `<select>` elements.

Comment: ok, whats the events valid to use on select element ?