# How to check if Foundation tabs are initialized?

Tags: javascript, tabs, zurb-foundation

According to docs there are 3 events https://get.foundation/sites/docs/tabs.html#js-events but none of them are what I'm looking for.

Ideally I would like to call a function once Foundation tabs have been initialized.

Comment: After page completely download. is this what you looking for? or specifically Foundation tabs?

Comment: @Kerim specifically when Foundation tabs are initialized if possible please.

Comment: Firstly all html element doesn't support `onload` event. You should use `<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <link>` or `<script>`. My suggestion is add someone from them after Foundation tabs and write a `onload="loadStart()"` event for it. Maybe this works for you. Could you please share result I'm wondering.

Comment: @Kerim All HTML elements are already there, so I don't have to use onload event. What I need to watch for is when tabs functionality get initialized and call some other function.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes)

Comment: We have events for all these cases in Foundation Sites. No need to use `onload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every component fires an `init` event.

See https://get.foundation/sites/docs/tabs.html#javascript-reference

> Fires these events: Tabs#event:init

The code is at https://github.com/foundation/foundation-sites/blob/v6.6.2/js/foundation.core.plugin.js#L22

So you have to listen for `init.zf.tabs`.

Comment: I don't know why but `init.zf.tabs` event isn't firing for me. Foundation version is `6.5.3` I'll have try to debug why is that.

Comment: Can you try the unminified version of foundation? Also please check if it works in 6.6.1 and 6.6.2. I think we fixed something regarding events in the minified version.

Comment: Also make sure to add the listener for the event before foundation / the component is initialized.